# Preventing a custom jquery function from merging joining when running at the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery

**I'm trying to write a simple jquery "addon" that types text out for me, like a typewriter.

This is what I've come up with so far:**

```js
jQuery.fn.typer=function(speed){
  typed = this;
  theText = typed.text().split('');
  typed.text("");
  $.each(theText, function(index, value){
    setTimeout(function(){
      typed.append(value);
    },speed*index);
  });
  return;
};


$("#p0").typer(50);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id='p0'>This text will appear at the speed: 50</p>
```

**This works perfectly fine until I try to get it to type out two sentences at once.**

```js
jQuery.fn.typer=function(speed){
  typed = this;
  theText = typed.text().split('');
  typed.text("");
  $.each(theText, function(index, value){
    setTimeout(function(){
      typed.append(value);
    },speed*index);
  });
  return;
};


$("#p0").typer(50);
$("#p1").typer(100);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id='p0'>This text will appear at the speed: 50</p><br />
<p id='p1'>This text will appear at the speed: 100</p>
```

**The result I get is: TThihs itesxt wtilel xaptpe arw ait lthle spaeepd:p 5e0ar at the speed: 100**

**Any clue on how I can stop this from happening?

Thanks in advance.**

Comment: What did you expect to happen when you launched two async functions in parallel with global variables?

Comment: When you leave out the `var` keyword, your variables become global !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declaring a variable without using the `var` keyword puts the variable in the global scope. See [this question for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470488/what-is-the-function-of-the-var-keyword-and-when-to-use-it-or-omit-it).
As such, both instances share the variables and result in the gibberish you see above.

```js
jQuery.fn.typer=function(speed){
  var typed = this;
  var theText = typed.text().split('');
  typed.text("");
  $.each(theText, function(index, value){
    setTimeout(function(){
      typed.append(value);
    },speed*index);
  });
  return;
};


$("#p0").typer(50);
$("#p1").typer(100);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id='p0'>This text will appear at the speed: 50</p><br />
<p id='p1'>This text will appear at the speed: 100</p>
```